# Guardar datos en una lista, y después validar si el dato existe en la lista

Tags: python, lista, validación

### **Crear un programa que guarde en una lista tantos nombres como el usuario desee, la captura debe detenerse cuando el usuario no ingrese ningún carácter. Después, el programa debe de ser capaz de decir si un nombre se encuentra en la lista creada.**

El IDE no me marca ningún problema, por lo que supongo el error es lógico o estoy usando de manera errónea las funciones.
Puedo grabar en la lista todos los datos sin problema alguno,pero detecto 2 errores en mi programa.

1. No puedo lograr que el programa finalice en caso de que el primer
   dato ingresado a la lista esté vacío.
2. Al momento de validar sí el dato se encuentra en la lista, siempre
   me arroja que el dato **si** existe en la lista, a pesar de que no
   sea así.

```py
import sys

name_list = [] #lista que guardará los nombres ingresados

ciclo = True #bucle infinito para guardar cuantos nombres quiera el usuario

while ciclo: #bucle infinito para guardar cuantos nombres quiera el usuario
    #name es la variable que irá agregando elementos a la lista
    name = str(input('Ingrese el nombre que desea agregar a la lista (para terminar de ingresar datos solo presione "Enter"):   '))

    if name != '':#si *name* tiene datos guardados, ejecutar:

        name_list += [name]  #agregar name a lista

        print(f'Hasta ahora la lista creada contiene los siguientes nombres:  {name_list}\n') #mostrar lista

    else: #Error 1: no puedo lograr que en caso de que el primer dato ingresado esté vacío, se muestre
          #lo siguiente por pantalla y termine mi programa; el programa siempre ignora este paso.

        if name_list == False:

            print('No se ha ingresado ningún dato \nFin del programa')

            sys.exit()

        print('\nEl ingreso de datos ha terminado\n')

        ciclo = False # fin de bucle infinito

#preguntar si se quiere conocer la existencia de un elemento en la lista
answ = str(input('\n¿Desea saber si alguno de los nombres se encuentra en la lista?\n'))

if answ == 'si' or answ == 'SI':
    #reciclo la variable answ, para saber si el proceso debe de ejecutarse una o más veces
    answ = str(input('¿Desea consultar más de un nombre?\n'))

    if answ == 'si' or answ == 'SI':

        ciclo = True #inicio de ciclo infinito en caso de que deseen consultar más de un dato

        while ciclo: #inicio de ciclo infinito en caso de que deseen consultar más de un dato

            name = str(input('¿Qué nombre desea consultar?\n')) #saber que dato desea conocer el usuario

            name in name_list #Error 2: el producto de esta validación es siempre True, a pesar de que el dato consultado
                              #no se encuentre en la lista

            if True:
                print(f'{name} sí se encuentra guardado en la lista\n')

            else:
                print(f'{name} no se encuentra guardado en la lista\n')

                repetir = str(input('¿Desea seguir consultando?\n')) #saber si se desea conocer más datos

                if repetir == 'no' or repetir == 'NO':
                    print('Fin del programa')
                    ciclo = False
    else: #ejecutar la validación del dato en la lista una sola vez

        name = str(input('¿Qué nombre desea consultar?\n'))

        name in name_list #El mismo error sucede aquí (Error 2)

        if True:
            print(f'{name} sí se encuentra guardado en la lista\n')
            print('Fin del programa')
            sys.exit()

        else:
            print(f'{name} no se encuentra guardado en la lista\n')
            print('Fin del programa')
            sys.exit()

else: #en caso de que no se desee conocer ningún dato

     print('Fin del programa')
     sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tus errores son los siguientes:

1. Para comprobar si la lista tiene algún dato has hecho `if name_list == False`, pero esa comparación no es correcta, ya que `False` es un valor de tipo booleano, mientras que `name_list` no (es de tipo `list`). Si querías comprobar si está vacía, deberás comparar con una lista vacía, es decir, `if name_list == []`. Otra posibilidad es mirar que tenga 0 elementos: `if len(name_list)==0`. Finalmente otra forma es `if not name_list` ya que cuando intentas evaluar una lista en el contexto de un `if` se considera falso (pero no `False`) una lista vacía, y por tanto verdadero (pero no `True`) la expresión `not name_list`.
2. Tienes un `if True`. La condición de ese `if` es `True`, por lo que siempre entra por él. Sin embargo, justo en la línea anterior tienes `name in name_list`, que es una expresión booleana cuyo resultado puede ser `True` o `False`, pero tal resultado "se pierde" al no asignarse a ningún sitio.

   Pareces pensar que quizás el hacer primero `name in name_list` crea una condición que puedas verificar después. Como si tu `if True` quisiera decir "si la expresión antes evaluada salió `True`". Pero no es eso lo que quiere decir `if True`. Quiere decir: "Si la expresión tras la palabra `if` es `True`" Y obviamente lo es, y siempre lo es.

   La sintaxis correcta por tanto es: `if name in name_list`, pues ahora la expresión tras la palabra `if` puede salir `True` o `False`, según el nombre esté o no en la lista.

Answer (score 2):

Respecto a los errores que comentas en el código:

Para comprobar si una lista esta vacía en python, uno de los métodos es simplemente utilizar:

```
 if len(name_list) == 0:
```

Lo único que estas haciendo al compararla con un booleano, en este caso 'False' es comprobar si la lista existe. Esto es útil para estructuras de datos como las pilas o stack, en caso de que quieras recorrer todos los elementos hasta que no tengas ninguno, utilizando por ejemplo:

```
while name_list:
```

Respecto a los otros dos errores, simplemente utiliza un state condicional, en este caso un 'if'

```
if name in name_list
```

Pues python no esta identificando correctamente la condición de la otra manera.

En cuanto a tus errores creo haber solucionado a pesar de que te aconsejo que utilices algún 'else' más pues es una buena practica de código ya que le da mas legibilidad.